# Check if Activity was called within my App

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume

How can I check if an Activity was called within my App?

My problem is, that I only want to update the Data if the user comes from another App and my is still in background.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A possible idea is to inverse the process, i.e. figuring out if the activity was started by your app.

Lets say you have an activity A in which you want to find out in onResume() whether you have come back from another activity of yours. You should be able to start all other activities, outgoing from A, with startActivityWithResult(), and check in onActivityResult() for the outcome. Since onActivityResult() is called before onResume(), you can set a boolean field to be checked in onResume().

So, the code is:

```
private static final int RANDOM_ACTION_CODE= 42;

private Button fButton;

private boolean returning= false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    fButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    fButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i= new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, RANDOM_ACTION_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Toast.makeText(this, "returning = " + returning, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RANDOM_ACTION_CODE)
        returning= true;
    else
        returning= false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the onRestart event?